# Advice on storing statistics in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, statistics, google-cloud-functions

In firestore i have documents with the fields, date and specimenCount.

Once a week i want to aggregate statistics grouping by date, that is all specimenCount should add upp for all dates that are the same.

Then i want to store it in a statistics collection for history reasons.

I am not sure If i should store the results in a map field or use the date as a filed no and specimenCount as the value.

Bottom line is to store it so it can be easy to read the history.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what your document look like?

Comment: Customers - history And under history there are several documents contaning fex, date: 08/14/2021, specimenCount: 3 and so on. I can share a screen dump tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the date as the doc id and specimenCount as value.
so, for document added today (28-08-2021), you add it like this

```
Future<void> storeAnalytics(dynamic data) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("analytics").doc(data['id']).set(
      {'value': FieldValue.increment(data['value']), 'date': data['date']},
      SetOptions(merge: true));
  // I used fieldValue.increment incase you have multiple data for 1 day.
  // SetOptions(merge: true), will prevent overwriting data if it already exists
  // I added date to the document incase in the future you want to fetch 
  // between a particular date range (eg. data for the year 2021). Here you can
  // just use a where query.
}

// call the above function like this
// you can create a function that returns date (without hypen or slash)
// from regular date and for use as doc id
await storeAnalytics({'id': '28082021', 'value': 'xxx', 'date': 'put in date'});


// In the future, if you want the data, you can call it like this
Future<dynamic> getAnalytics(DateTime start, DateTime end) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('analytics/')
      .orderBy('date', descending: true)
      .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: start)
      .where('date', isLessThan: end).get();
}
```

It makes no sense to do this on the device, rather create a cloud function to handle this. Javascript Template given below.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("/path-to-document/")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const value = snap.data();
    const specimentCount = value.value;
    const timestamp = value.date;
    const date = timestampToDate(timestamp);
    const id = timestampToDayId(timestamp);

    return db.doc("analytics/" + id)
      .set(
        { data: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(specimentCount), date },
        { merge: true },
      );
  });
// if your document can be updated and deleted, you can add a listeners for 
// that.

/**
 * Returns javascript date (YYYYMMDD) from firebase timestamp.
 * @param {timestamp} timestamp The firebase timestamp.
 * @return {Date} The javascript date.
 */
function timestampToDate(timestamp) {
  const date = timestamp.toDate();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  return date;
}

/**
 * Returns full id from firebase timestamp.
 * @param {timestamp} timestamp The firebase timestamp.
 * @return {String} The id.
 */
function timestampToDayId(timestamp) {
  const date = timestamp.toDate();
  let day = date.getDate();
  if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;

  let month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;

  return date.getFullYear() + "" + month + "" + day;
}
```

One advantage of using cloud functions is that you can restrict write for analytics collection using firestore rules. Only allow read (cloud function does not need to be granted firestore access). Another benefit is that this task won't take device resources.

Comment: Very nice! Exactly what i needed!