# How should I dynamically query the data per month?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'll be using reactjs and chartjs to create this. Though I do not have the codes yet, I would only like to ask for advice or to have a better understanding before coding it. In firestore, I already have this data:

[image]

I wanted to dynamically query it per vaccine and per month. What I somewhat thought of to do was to have a selection for the user to choose what year and what type of vaccine. I kind of thought of these codes however, dynamically querying it per month was quite difficult:

the `selectedVaccine` - is the variabale for the select where users can choose what type of vaccine.

`db.collection("users") .where("doses.selectedVaccine","==", selectedVaccine) .where("doses.firstDose","==", true)`

Any advice would be appreciated about querying it per month. Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to get all documents within a month?

Comment: @Dharmaraj like per month from Jan-Dec since I'll be using a graph.

Comment: If you are fetching all the documents for the graphs, why not filter on client side using Javascript? It'll be much more easier I believe.

Comment: @Dharmaraj How? Do you have any example or reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection("users")
  .where("doses.selectedVaccine","==", selectedVaccine)
  .where("doses.firstDose","==", true)
  .where("doses.firstDose", ">=" start)
  .where("doses.firstDose", "<" end);
  // change doses.firstDose to whichever date you want to use.
```

For any start and end date (e.g 1st Jan 2020 and 31st Dec 2020), the above query should return all first doses within that time frame.

Then you can loop through the results and place them in arrays depending on their months. Array of all Januaries first doses in position 0, Array of all Februaries first doses in position 1 etc.

This will involve downloading the full data of all doses for a year. If your intention is just to plot a chart, then consider this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967331/10136013)

Comment: I would need cloud functions to this query?

Comment: You won't need cloud functions for this answer, but the answer in the link will require it. The answer in the link has 2 parts flutter and cloud functions. you can use the cloud functions part.

Comment: So I could still query this per month without needing the cloud function, right?

Comment: Yes. You can. This does not need cloud function.